# $.ajax vs $.post : getting allow origin error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Doing ajax using this is fine :

```
$.post("http://localhost:3000/scrape",
            {
                data: json
            },
            function(data, status){
            });
```

but this is not?

```
$.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'http://localhost:3000/scrape',
              data: json,
              contentType: "application/json",
              success: function(data,status){

              },
              async:false
            });
```

With $.ajax I got the error of 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/scrape. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I thought both of them are the same? What's the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

In the first example you are making a simple request with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

In the second example you are specifying a content type which isn't one of the ones allowed for simple requests, so you are triggering a [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

The server is responding happily to the POST request, but not to the preflight OPTIONS request.

Comment: nice, and as a matter of interest could you explain what would be the benefit of triggering the preflight request? Is it because it is safer?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald — As explained by MDN: "Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may have implications to user data."